# How to detect PrimeNG sidebar close icon and other button clicks within the sidebar

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

Im trying to revert the changes if user clicks on close icon and save it if clicked on save button.
But in [PrimeNG Sidebar](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v13/sidebar) documentation i cant find the way to handle both the click events separately. Is it possible to do so?

[image: Sidebar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are overthinking things. The close button shown by the PrimeNG variable showCloseIcon is handled by PrimeNG itself. All it does is close the sidebar element. If you want to code custom behaviour you will have to code your own buttons.

For the closing behaviour of the PrimeNG close button you can hook into the onHide event and couple a function to that. For the save button you simply hook into the onClick as with any other Angular event.

So in code:
HTML

```
<p-sidebar [(visible)]="display" (onHide)="close()">
  <!-- Your form -->
  <button (click)="save()">Save</button>
</p-sidebar>
```

HTML in case of a custom close button

```
<p-sidebar [(visible)]="display">
  <button (click)="close()"><span class="x-button">&times;</span></button>
  <!-- Your form -->
  <button (click)="save()">Save</button>
</p-sidebar>
```

CSS for button

```
span .x-button {
    color:gray;
    opacity:0.7;
    font-size:1.5em;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function save() {...}
function close() {...//set display to false and do what you need to do}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: onhide is triggered on each close event, the only issue is i cant seem to differentiate between which caused it to close

Comment: In that case I recommend not using the built-in close button and instead going for a custom button with a click event.

Comment: thanks for the input i have disabled inbuilt close button and placed a custom one :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! Don't forget to mark answered :)